# Exportar vistas de laravel en pdf

Tags: laravel, pdf, laravel-blade, controller, exportar

estoy intentando exportar una vista de laravel en formato pdf, la cosa es que estoy utilizando datos dentro de esa vista y al momento de exportar, me dice que no existe alguna de las variables con el error `Undefined variable $datoshojas`,estoy utilizando las librerias de `barryvdh/laravel-dompdf` para intentar hacer dicha accion de exportar, pero me sigue dando este error.

Adjunto la funcion de mi controlador:

```
    public function pdf()
    {
        $registros = Registro::all();
        $datoshojas = Datoshoja::all();
        $options = option::all();
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('hojaschequeo.hojas5-7.F7-SETCS-ELE-CR-L1-01.index')
        ->with('registros',$registros)
        ->with('datoshojas',$datoshojas)
        ->with('options', $options);
        return $pdf-> download();
    }
```

y mi ruta:

```
Route::get('/pdf',[DatoshojaController::class,'pdf'])->name('pdf');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tuve que reconstruir la parte del controlador, ya que como estaba no me estaba trayendo las variables de los datos que necesitaba, al final me quedo de esta forma.

```
    public function pdfprint()
    {
        $registros = Registro::all();
        $datoshojas = Datoshoja::all();
        $options = option::all();
        view()-> share('datoshojas',$datoshojas);
        view()-> share('registros',$registros);
        view()-> share('options',$options);
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('hojaschequeo.hojas5-7.F7-SETCS-ELE-CR-L1-01.printindex');
        $pdf->setPaper('b3','landscape');
        return $pdf-> stream();
    }
```

los tres primeros me traen todos los datos, luego con la vista me ayuda a manejarlo para que no me salga el error al traer los datos, algo asi como el with en un index, y por ultimo cargo la vista en el pdf para al ultimo devolver el pdf, en este caso, con stream lo que hago es generarme el pdf pero no guardarlo.